# Session is reseting on RedirectToAction across controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one loginController With Index Mathod as

```
public ActionResult Index(string something)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session["ActiveUser"] = _user;
    return RedirectToAction("All", "User");
}
```

and UserContoller as

```
     public ActionResult All()
     {
        var _currentUser = ((AuthUser)Session["ActiveUser"]);
     }
```

the problem is when redirect Happens the session state resets, I am not able to understand why ?
any help or resource will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using both Session and TempData? Why not use just the TempData?

Comment: i am using them and none of them is working ,I have tried using them individually also , it may be left behind from cleaning @Igor

Comment: Ok. TempData also uses the Session storage under the covers, its more of an MVC construct than Session and if you are only persisting state across a Request (using the redirect in this case) then its better to only use that instead of Session. How do you have Session storage configured in the web.config (you can also see the configuration in IIS)?

Comment: there is no special configuration of Session in the webconfig @Igor

Comment: if you have fetched data from the TempData and then redirected it, then  the data in TempData will become null.

Comment: @anand I haven't fetched it , I have assigned the value , the access is done in the other controller, tried , with TempData.Keep(key) also not working with that to

Comment: thats what i meant. use only session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

> I had also written Session.Abandon(); in the start when I removed that from I code it started working fine.

Yeah, that would explain it. Calling `Session.Abandon` queues the Session for destruction/removal and executes it when your initial request (before the redirect starts) finishes processing. So anything you do to Session (including TempData) in that initial request is essentially ignored because the entire session including changes is discarded. [From the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx).

> When the Abandon method is called, the current Session object is queued for deletion but is not actually deleted until all of the script commands on the current page have been processed. This means that you can access variables stored in the Session object on the same page as the call to the Abandon method but not in any subsequent Web pages.

---

> there is no special configuration of Session in the webconfig @Igor

Then the Session state is not enabled which is why you can't retrieve anything from `Session` or `TempData`. You need to configure the session state in the web.config. If you are only using this for TempData you can configure it for `InProc`. If you want to configure long term storage (data available across multiple requests) and you have multiple servers (ie. web farm) that can handle requests you should look at configuration using a store like Sql Server.

You can make the configuration changes either directly in the `web.config` ([see SessionState documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.71).aspx))

```
<sessionState mode="Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer"
          cookieless="true|false"
          timeout="number of minutes"
          stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"
          sqlConnectionString="sql connection string"
          stateNetworkTimeout="number of seconds"/>
```

Or using IIS (see screenshot below).

[image: IIS Session State]

Comment: okay I'll try to use it ,but before that just one doubt, I had the same webconfig(without anyspecific settings and [HttpPost] Index(LoggedUser) Method which was used to hit on form-submit ,  and session and everything was working over there  , I am not able understand this behaviour.

My IIS settings are same as you have defined in you screenshot

Comment: is it may be because I am running two localhost:x, and localhost:y where y takes some call from x , and then x redirects it with some token

Comment: @Vikas - If you have multiple hosts that communicate between each other then most likely they will not be able to share session state. In that case this would be the root problem. If they are multiple servers running the same web application (like a web farm scenerio) then you could configure both servers to use a central store like Sql Server and then they could both access Session state.

Comment: I had also written Session.Abandon(); in the start when I removed that from I code it started working fine , any Idea @igor